# unexpected TOKBEGIN, expecting AFFECT or SEMICOLON

Tags: vhdl, counter

I'm new to vhdl i've written the code for 12-bit binary counter and i'm getting this error (unexpected TOKBEGIN, expecting AFFECT or SEMICOLON). Kindly guide me to resolve this error

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity bin_count is
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       seq : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0));
end bin_count;

architecture Behavioral of bin_count is
signal  ff, ff_next, max_pulse : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
begin
process(clk,reset)
begin
if(reset = '1') then
ff <= "000000000000"
elsif( rising_edge(clk)) then
ff <= ff_next
end if
end process;
ff_next <= ff + 1;
max_pulse <= '1' when ff = "111111111111" else
0;
seq<= ff
end

end Behavioral;
```

error is;

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "C:/.Xilinx/New folder/bin_count/bin_count.vhd" Line 39. parse error, unexpected TOKBEGIN, expecting AFFECT or SEMICOLON
```

Comment: There's a lot of missing semicolons in that code, exactly as the error message says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your profile shows you haven't take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (found under Help). The Tour suggests searching the site before asking a question. Searching in this case doesn't find a single answered question for ERROR:HDLParsers:164 also mentioning an expected semicolon.

In VHDL a semicolon is a separator for statements and declarations. The use is so basic that you can't find the requirement exhibited anywhere else in the LRM but the Extended BNF which addresses how to parse a VHDL syntax.

That you missed a lot of semicolons likely means no mention of the use of separators is presented where you were introduced to VHDL.

**Errors in your example code**
In addition to 5 missing semicolons there is no visible "+" operator (ff is not an unsigned or signed value - use package numeric_std_unsigned instead of numeric_std or use type conversions).

The assignment to max_plus choices are not expressions of values of std_logic_vector's subtype max_plus  ("111111111111" and "0000000000000" instead of '1' and 0).

There's an errant (extra) end statement (also without a semicolon).

The first error shows up on line 26 of your example, there is no line 39. You could have pointed out the location.

```
architecture behavioral of bin_count is
    signal  ff, ff_next, max_pulse: 
            std_logic_vector(11 downto 0); -- missing semicolon
begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            ff <= "000000000000";          -- missing semicolon
        elsif  rising_edge(clk) then
            ff <= ff_next;                 -- missing semicolon
        end if;                            -- missing semicolon
    end process;

   --  ff_next <= ff + 1;     -- no visible operator "+"
   ff_next <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(ff) + 1); -- type converts ff to unsigned
                                                  -- and the result back
    -- or in the context clause use numeric_std_unsigned:
-- use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;  -- makes "+" visible
    -- instead of numeric_std;
    -- 
    -- and here:
    -- ff_next <= ff + 1;

    -- abstract literal 0  and enumeration literal '1' are not values
    -- of std_logic_vector:

    -- max_pulse <= '1' when ff = "111111111111" else
    --              '0'; 

    -- use string literal instead:
    max_pulse <= "111111111111" when ff = "111111111111" else
                 "000000000000";

    -- (and there are other expressions available)

    seq <= ff;                              -- missing semicolon
-- end         -- errant end statement - this doesn't match anything.

end behavioral;
```

And with the mentioned changes your code analyzes. There are some other changes that can be made.

`max_pulse` doesn't need to be a std_logic_vector, it can be a std_logic. (This would allow the use of '1' and '0' as the values assigned in the conditional assignment statement.

There is no need for `ff_next`.

These give us a slightly different architecture:

```
architecture foo of bin_count is
    signal  ff:         std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    signal max_pulse:   std_logic;
begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            ff <= (others => '0');         -- an aggregate
        elsif  rising_edge(clk) then
            ff <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(ff) + 1); 
        end if;                  
    end process;   

    max_pulse <= '1' when ff = "111111111111" else
                 '0';                 
    seq <= ff;

end architecture;
```

With a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bin_count_tb is
end entity;

architecture fum of bin_count_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0'; -- default value
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal seq:     std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns; -- half the clock period
        clk <= not clk; 
        if now > 85000 ns then -- now returns simulation time
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DUT:    
    entity work.bin_count
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            seq => seq
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 11 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

We can see the reset:

[image: bin_count_tb_reset.png]
*(clickable)*

We can see `max_pulse` occurs periodically:

[image: bin_count_tb_max_pulse_repeats.png]
*(clickable)*

And we can see `max_pulse occurs` when `seq = "111111111111"`:

[image: bin_count_tb_max_pulse.png]
*(clickable)*